# Binding Mapsui Map to Xaml and with MVVM and service architecture

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, inversion-of-control, winui, mapsui

**Goal:**

I try to display a map from Mapsui with MVVM and a service.
And CommunityToolkit.Mvvm is installed and can be used for the ViewModel.

**My error:**

Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' in WinRT.Runtime.dll
WinRT information: Failed to assign to property 'Mapsui.UI.WinUI.MapControl.Map'. [Line: 18 Position: 119]
XAML parsing failed.

And its happens in the code-behind file:

```
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

I don’t think I created the Map for the Xaml file but how to bind it correctly?
With  `Map="{Binding Map}"` or `DataContext`? Or something else?

[My simple github project is public](https://github.com/hfbdynatest/MapsuiMMVMCross).

**My xaml file**

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <viewmodels:MapViewModel/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <winui:MapControl x:Name="MyMap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Map="{Binding Map}"/>
    </Grid>
```

**My Code-behind file**

`Datacontext = ViewModel`  or something?

```
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

**My ViewModel code**

```
    public partial class MapViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        //[ObservableProperty]
        private Map _map;

        private readonly IMapService mapService;

        public MapViewModel()
        {
            mapService = new MapService();
            Map = mapService.GetMap();
        }

        public Map Map
        {
            get => _map;
            set => SetProperty(ref _map, value);
        }
    }
```

**MapService**

```
    public class MapService : IMapService
    {

        private Map _map;
        public MapService()
        {
            _map = new Map();
        }

        public Map GetMap()
        {
            _map.Layers.Add(OpenStreetMap.CreateTileLayer());
            return _map;
        }
    }
```

```
    public interface IMapService
    {
        Map GetMap();
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I know the problem